# One word for - Missed something in big chunk/group of things

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I have a document and want to mention to others that "Keep this document aside to avoid mixing with other bunch of docs for an easy reference".

What can be a one word for "avoid mixing with other bunch of things" ?

I'm not sure why are people down-voting ?

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, and add an example sentence with a blank where you want the word to appear?

Comment: Context of usage: I have a document and want to mention to others that "Please keep this document aside to avoid mixing with other bunch of docs for an easy reference". I'm looking for a one word for  "avoid mixing with other bunch of docs"

Comment: Keep this document [handy/close-at-hand] for easy reference.

Comment: People tend to downvote because when you ask for "one word," they expect you to know the [single-word request tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) (which I have added to your question). And such requests require an example sentence with a blank where the word you want goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

"Please keep this document apart from other documents to allow for easy reference."